# Nim Lang - Finding char index

Tags: nim-lang

I appreciate this is a very newbie question, I just came across Nim 2 days ago and thought I'd give it some investigation. but I'm not finding the documentation to be very intuitive.

I have used the following code to get a list of files

```
const dataPath:string = r"/Users/xyz/Dev/Nim"

proc listFilesRecursively(dirPath: string) =
  for entry in walkDirRec(dirPath):
    echo("Filename: ",entry.splitPath.tail, ", Path: ",entry.normalizedPath)
    #echo rfind(entry,'/',start=30)

listFilesRecursively(dataPath)
```

I have managed to find the last occurance of '/' in by using reverse find `rfind()`. But I'm trying to find index of the next occurance of '/' so I can extract the substring between the last and 2nd to last occurances of '/'.

I've tried settings different values to the `start` parameter, and even used `rfind(entry,'/',start=rfind(entry,'/'))` to try and make it find the next index after the first. But I cannot get it to work.

I might have the following structure in the directory

- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder1/PEOPLE/file1.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder1/PEOPLE/file2.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder1/SALES/file1.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder1/SALES/file2.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder2/PEOPLE/file1.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder2/PEOPLE/file2.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder2/SALES/file1.csv
- /Users/xyz/Dev/folder2/SALES/file2.csv

I'm looking to get the substring of **people and sales**, so I can group all files from all 'sales' folders into one key/pair value, and group all files from 'people' foldes into another key pair value (dictionary in python, in nim?). I will then loop through the files in each group, import the CSV files and upload them to a database (SQL server 2019, if it is possible?)

Many thanks for your help.

I also tried chatGPT but it doesn't seem to understand much about the nim syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `entry.parentDir.lastPathPart` from the
[os module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html) should give you the correct path component.

For key/value pairs have a look at `Table` from [tables](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html).

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much @Marc!. I shall now go learn about tables, which ironically sounds like the name I would use for 'dataframes" which I need in the next step when importing my CSV's.

Answer (score 0):

Nim `os` module is very well equiped. You could search for directories *only* in a recursive way with this:

```
for d in walkDirRec(".", yieldFilter={pcDir}):
   ...
```

Then look for specific directories, walking only on those you want:

```
   case d.splitPath().tail
   of "SALES":
     for f in walkDirRec(d):
       echo "Sales Csv: ", f
   of "PEOPLE":
     for f in walkDirRec(d):
       echo "People Csv": ", f
```